# Utilizing the Factorization Theorem on unknown distributions

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I have two unknown distributions

\begin{align*}
    f(x;\theta) &= \frac{1}{x\cdot \ln \theta} & 1 < x < \theta 
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
    f(x;\beta) = \frac{\beta}{(1+x)^{\beta+1}} \hspace{2cm} x > 0
\end{align*}

And I am trying to find the sufficient statistic for x as follows; Find the sufficient statistic $u(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for $\beta$ and $\delta$.

So far I have tried to simplify it to follow the $\phi$ and $h$ format but I am stuck.

I have gotten as follows for the first distribution

\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\theta) = f(x_1;\theta) \cdot f(x_2;\theta) \cdot f(x_3;\theta)\cdot ... \cdot f(x_n;\theta)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\theta) = \frac{1}{(\ln \theta)^n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i} = \frac{1}{(\ln \theta)^n} \cdot \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}
\end{equation*}

and here for the second.

\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n;\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\frac{\beta}{(1+x_i)^{\beta+1}}\Big)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    f(x_1,x_2,x_3...x_n;\beta) = \Big(\frac{\beta^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)^{\beta + 1}}\Big)
\end{equation*}

Am I missing any steps or is there an easier way to approach this problem?

Comment: The second one should be a product in the denominator, not a sum. What easier way than this?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I made a typo and have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: Could you point out where exactly you are stuck? You have pretty much solved the problem.

Comment: I do not know how i can describe what the sufficient statistic here. In the first equation, I have isolated the X but it is a product not a sum. And in the second equation, I can't isolate the X

Comment: I understand that, but in the first equation there is no function i can find to describe $g(\theta,t)$ because the $\frac{1}{(\ln \theta)^n}$ only depends on the parameter, similarly in the second equation $\beta^n$ depends on the parameter only

Comment: I apologize but I still don't fully understand how to break down the two equations according to the Factorization theorem.

Comment: Sorry I had overlooked the $1<x<\theta$ restriction in my comments before and in my answer below. So do have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorization theorem says that if joint density $f_{\theta}$ of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ factors as

$$f_{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g(\theta,t)h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,,$$

where $g$ depends on $\theta$ and on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, where the dependence on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is through $t=t(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ only, and $h$ is independent of $\theta$, then $t(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

It is important to keep track of the support of the joint distribution, especially when the support depends on the unknown parameter.

So for the first problem, joint density of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (assuming independence) is

\begin{align}
f_{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac1{x_i\ln\theta}\mathbf1_{1<x_i<\theta}
\\&=\frac{1}{(\ln\theta)^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i}\cdot \mathbf1_{1<x_1,\ldots,x_n<\theta}
\\&=\underbrace{\frac{\mathbf1_{1<x_{(n)}<\theta}}{(\ln\theta)^n}}_{g(\theta,t)} \cdot \underbrace{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{-1}}_{h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}
\end{align}

Here $x_{(n)}=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $\mathbf1_{x\in A}$ is an indicator function which equals $1$ if $x\in A$ and equals $0$ if $x\notin A$.

You can see $g(\theta,t)$ depends on $\theta$ and it depends on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ through $t=x_{(n)}$.

Do this for the second problem. If you have any difficulty in the algebra, simply solve the problems for $n=2$ first to see the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you solved the question? If your queries are addressed adequately, you should accept and/or upvote answers.